# Is there a way for an application to send emails using SMTP with an account which is 2FA enabled while also not having access to the app password?

Tags: python, email, smtplib, multi-factor-authentication

Our Flask application currently supports sending emails via SMTP (using Python's `smtplib` library), but the sender email available to us has 2FA enabled and app password disabled.

Given that we cannot use app passwords and 2FA is enabled, is it possible to send via SMTP or is there any other way of sending emails from this particular account using any service that works with 2FA?

When we try sending via SMTP using username/password, we get below error:

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [PN3PR01CA0027.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')
```

Comment: For what server?  Assuming you’re talking about Gmail, the proper way to do this is with OAuth, where the user logs in once/authorizes you, and you get an oauth token to use for the future.  However, Google highly restricts what applications can use email.  But, more fundamentally: does your app need to be From: the user?  Normally you would use some sort of service account (yourapp@yourapp.com) and say who you’re on sending on behalf of (either in the body of your mail, or using a Sender/From: pair)

Comment: @Max Its for Outlook. Yes it would need to be from a particular user. Is there an equivalent for a service account which we can use for Microsoft email?

Comment: Sorry I do not know the finer points of Microsoft’s authentication options. You may get further using their HTTP interfaces, which are a bit better documented.